# In wordpress ajax load doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have tried the following code to load word-press register form when one will click on the link register, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="section-register"></div>

<a class="get-register" href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register</a>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.get-register').click( function(e) {
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        jQuery("div#section-register").load(url, "form#registerform");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No, no error. Plz help. I'm suffering with it for long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is `<div class="section-register"></div>`

and you selecting the div by `id`
change your `jQuery("div#section-register").load(url, "form#registerform");` to

```
jQuery("div.section-register").load(url, "form#registerform");
```

OR

change the markup to `<div id="section-register"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad luck.